# How to wrap admin views in django?

Tags: python, django

I have some custom code that I want to execute before calling any of the admin views.  In concept it seems simple enough; just create a wrapper view that does what I want, then wrap all of the admin views in it.  But how do I do that?

Here's the relevant portion of my main urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Is there a way to wrap all of the admin views without having to specify each one individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decorate all the routed functions by creating a separate `urls` module, importing `admin.site.urls`, then dynamically constructing your `urlpatterns` based on the data you read from `admin.site.urls.urlpatterns`. I wouldn't suggest modifying the routed functions in the admin `urls` module because the patterns are exposed through a static reference.

But the proper approach would be to write [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) that can interject the view processing in the same phases as decorators: before the view is called with the request, after it throws an exception or returns a response.